# OOM due to Idle DB connections in Tomcat's ConnectionPool

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat8

I am using Tomcat 8.0.27, OpenJDK 8 update 71 & Oracle 11.2.0.3.0. Driver version is Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.3). I've encountered with OOM error.

[image: Memory Leak Detector]

**I drilled down to the connection pool object, where the biggest object is the idle connections list:**

[image: Tomcat Pooled Connections]

Zooming into idle connection list showed that the memory held by **oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection$BufferCacheStore**:

[image: Idle connection list]

[image: PhysicalConnection]

My assumption is that those buffers were allocated by previous connection holder and since my pool configuration allows to hold up to 30 idle connections they won't release until the idle limit reach.

My DB pool configuration is:

```
  <bean id="dataSourcePoolProperties" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties">
                <property name="driverClassName">
                    <value>${db.driverClass}</value>
                </property>
                <property name="url">
                    <value>${db.url_prefix}:@${db.host}:${db.port}:${db.sid}</value>
                </property>
                <property name="username">
                    <value>${db.user}</value>
                </property>
                <property name="password">
                    <value>${db.password}</value>
                </property>
                <property name="maxActive">
                    <value>50</value>
                </property>
                <property name="maxIdle">
                    <value>30</value>
                </property>
                <property name="initialSize">
                    <value>10</value>
                </property>
                <property name="testOnBorrow">
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property name="testOnReturn">
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property name="validationQuery">
                    <value>select 1 from dual</value>
                </property>
                <property name="name">
                    <value>Main DataSource</value>
                </property>
                <property name="jmxEnabled">
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
                <property name="logValidationErrors">
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </bean>
```

I know that Oracle's driver allocates the buffer according to maximum possible query size. Inspecting their content revealed many zeros there.

### **Edit 1:**

The Oracle's driver jar file is in the WEB-INF/lib folder while the tomcat-jdbc.jar under CATALINA_HOME/lib folder. I know that this can be problematic for re deployments but we don't do that.

Can you suggest a way to dismiss the internal driver buffers?

Comment: is it that you're having an app that's not releasing its connections properly, or do you experience this even without apps deployed?

Comment: since the connections located under idle list I assume that the app release them properly.

Comment: but you're not having this issue without the app (or an app) deployed, right?

Comment: No, we deploy only one app.

Comment: What is you pool config? (maxIdle, maxActive etc), are you sure your app is releasing connection (as already asked by eis)?

Comment: I added my pool configuration to the question. Yes, the error happened once during repeating automation process.

Comment: @MaximKirilov It looks like a memory leak problem. can you confirm if you are doing hot deployment of your web app and whether your oracle driver jar file is in the web-inf/lib folder? If so, you can move this oracle driver jar file tomcat/lib and try. It looks like the parent classloader is unable release the webapp classloader during the hot deployment because oracle jdbc driver is in web-inf/lib folder. By the way, are you seeing an memory leak warnings on tomcat logs during hot deployment?

Comment: We don't use hot deployment.Our app deployed on Tomcat's start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the OOM caused due to change that we made in driver fetch size, the number of rows to retrieve on each fetch. With the size of each
column and the number of rows, the driver can compute the absolute maximum size of the data returned in a single fetch. This is probably what caused to pre allocated buffers to grow.

Careful reading of Oracle's Driver documentation revealed that

**"The 11.2 driver has a more sophisticated buffer cache than 11.1.0.7.0. This buffer cache has
multiple buckets. All buffers in a bucket are of the same size and that size is predetermined..
When a PreparedStatement is executed for the first time the driver gets a buffer from the bucket
holding the smallest size buffers that will hold the result. If there is no buffer in the bucket, the
driver allocates a new buffer of the predefined size corresponding to the bucket. When a
PreparedStatement is closed, the buffers are returned to their appropriate buckets. Since buffers
are used for a range of size requirements, the buffers are usually somewhat larger than the
minimum required."**

After rolling back the fetch size argument the OOM error gone away.